# Scheme (DrRacket) lambda expression

Tags: function, lambda, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I do not understand the following program code. Can anyone explain it to me?

```
(define myFunction
  (lambda (f x y z)
    (f x y z)))
```

How can I simplify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't simplify it much, except for making it look a bit syntactic, as

```
(define (myFunction f x y z)
        (f x y z))
```

which is a syntactic shortcut for defining the exact same thing.

This way, you can treat it mentally as a rewriting rule: whenever you see

```
        (myFunction f x y z)
```

in your code - *whatever* those `f`, `x`, `y` and `z` placeholders are referring to - you can replace it with

```
        (f x y z)
```

while substituting the actual values, a.k.a. arguments, for the placeholders, a.k.a. function parameters.

Thus you see that for the new code to make sense, `f` should be a function capable of accepting three arguments, `x`, `y` and `z`.

So for example, if you define `(define (f x y z) (+ x y z))`, you can call

```
(myFunction f 1 2 3)
```

and get a result back - which is the result of calling the function `f` you've just defined above, with the values *1*, *2* and *3*.

`f` inside `myFunction` will refer to the global name `f` which refers to a value - a function named `f` you've defined. The `lambda` form defines a value - an anonymous function - and `define` *binds* a name `f` to it, so that any use of that name refers to that value, from now on. In Scheme, *functions* are values like any other.

That global function `f` is defined to apply `+` to the three arguments it receives, *when* it receives them. It in effect is saying, "give me some three values and I'll sum them up for you", and the call `(myFunction f 1 2 3)` supplies it with the three values of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

`lambda ...` creates a function which expects 4 arguments, the first of which (`f`) should itself be a function. `(f x y z)` applies this `f` to the other 3 arguments.

`define` gives the name `myFunction` to the lambda.

Comment: thank for you answer. but if you mean so (define (f x y z)
  (+ x y z))
the second f in lambda expresions still not work. It shows following error message (function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but found a variable)